# Commit or handle rollback in stored procedure after insertions are done?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Optimal way to handle an error in stored procedure that only makes inserts?

I have a procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_TO_TABLES (VAL1 IN NUMBER, VAL2 IN NUMBER, RESULT OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (A_COLUMN) VALUES (VAL1);
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (B_COLUMN) VALUES (VAL2);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

How could I make this stored procedure optimal enough to handle a rollback and raise an exception to catch from the application (C# try/catch) if only 1 of those inserts throws an error? Return out value true if everything is ok or false if an error happened?

Comment: raise an exception and let the C# client determine rollback/commit.

Comment: @OldProgrammer sorry to not mention, im using ado.net and to my understanding, i can't rollback or commit from C# but I can handle the exception if its raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLERRM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/sqlerrm.php) and [SQLCODE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/sqlcode.php) functions may be used :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_TO_TABLES (VAL1 IN NUMBER, VAL2 IN NUMBER, RESULT OUT 
NUMBER, RESULT_ERR OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
 v_err_code number         := SQLCODE;   
 v_err_txt  varchar2(4000) := SQLERRM;
Begin
  Begin
    INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (A_COLUMN) VALUES (VAL1);
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (B_COLUMN) VALUES (VAL2);
   Exception When Others then                 
             RESULT_ERR := v_err_code||' '||v_err_txt;
  End;

  If ( nvl(v_err_code,0)<0 ) Then
    ROLLBACK;
  Else 
    RESULT_ERR :='Committed with success...';
    COMMIT;
  End If;
End;
```